# Is it possible to extract geometric transforms from ImageStitch (Mathematica 13)?

Tags: image-processing, geometric-transform

Is there a way to extract the Method settings and/or geometric transforms that ImageStitch[] (Mathematica 13) uses to compose a list of images? I have ~40 digital microscope image frames along with the associated surface height data for each frame in {x,y,z} format. I've previously used FindGeometricTransform[] to obtain translations between pairs of frames, and then convolved those translations to align the {x,y,z} data sets for interpolation. However, with my current set of images there are several frame pairs for which ImageAlign[] and FindGeometricTransform[] fail to find acceptable alignments (likely due to insufficient overlap), while ImageStitch[] does a much better job.

Using FindGeometicTransform[] I get the following alignment:

```
xsiz = 1920;
ysiz = 1200;
jpg1 = Import["/home/akw/Forsterite500umLoose_24Aug2022/Frame01.jpg"];
jpg2 = Import["/home/akw/Forsterite500umLoose_24Aug2022/Frame02.jpg"];
{e, tr} = FindGeometricTransform[jpg1, jpg2, TransformationClass -> "Translation"];
ImageCrop[ImageCompose[ImagePad[jpg1, {{xsiz, xsiz}, {ysiz, ysiz}}, White], ImagePerspectiveTransformation[jpg2, tr, DataRange -> Full, PlotRange -> All, Background -> White], {xsiz, ysiz} + tr[{0, 0}], {0, 0}]]
```

[image: Alignment obtained with FindGeometricTransform]

Whereas, if I use ImageStitch[] the alignment is much better (though I don't understand why the color has been altered):

```
ImageStitch[{jpg1, jpg2}, TransformationClass -> "Translation", Method -> {"ImageBlending" -> None}]
```

[image: Alignment obtained with ImageStitch]

So I'd like to A) obtain the geometric transforms used by ImageStitch[] or B) apply the settings used by ImageStitch[] to FindGeometricTransform[] if either are possible.

Many thanks,

Adam

Comment: `FindGeometricTransform` has a special `Method` option `Method -> {"ImageAlign", ImageAlignMethod}` for extracting the `TransformationFunction` generated by `ImageAlign`. Since there is no similar option for `ImageStitch`, I doubdt it is possible. It would be useful to have such an option though (+1). You could write a *suggestion for improvement* to Wolfram with this idea.

Comment: You can try using `ImageAlign` instead of `ImageStitch` for your purpose.